# Compare 2 tables and update final table with the row which has max value Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables **TableA** and **Final_Table**

TableA

```
ID  Step1   Step2   Step3 Step4
1    1       1       0     0   --Update Final_table for Id1 with these values as more steps have 1
2    1       1       1     0
3    1       1       1     1   --Since 3 doesn't exist in Final table insert row in final table
```

Final_Table

```
   ID  Step1   Step2   Step3 Step4
   1    1       0       0     0
   2    1       1       1     1 --Keep this as more steps have 1 in it
   4    0       0       0     0 --since Id4 doesn't exist in Table
```

After Running the Query I want the final_table to look like below

Final_Table

```
   ID  Step1   Step2   Step3 Step4
   1    1       1       0     0
   2    1       1       1     1
   3    1       1       1     1
   4    0       0       0     0
```

Whenever a Id exists in both table I want to Update the Final_Table with data which has max steps as 1. I would appreciate any help!Thanks in advance

Comment: check [DML's MERGE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) and show us what you tried - so we can help you then

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant ! I didn't know about MERGE statement. Worked perfectly

Comment: Great, feel free to post answer to your question, it might help someone else :o) at the same time you have chance to increase your reputation if your answer will be upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I used Merge and Update to solve my question - It worked liked a charm. I created a sumT column of all steps in my Final_Table. Might help someone

First query:

```
MERGE final_Table T
USING (SELECT id, SUM(of all columns) AS sumA 
       FROM TableA 
       GROUP BY Id FROM TableA) S ON T.id = S.id

WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET sum = greatest(sumA, sumT)

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (id, sumT) VALUES (id,sumA)
```

Second query:

```
UPDATE Final_Table AS 1 OR 0 depending on SumT
```

Hope it helps!